# How to adapt my union query to provide consolidated values

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have the below query. It sizes all indexes, lobs and table segments for each schema listed in a "driver table"... over a db_link. It seems to work just fine, however, instead of giving a value for each Table, as "T", each Index as "I" and each LOB as "L", I want it to just give a size for each schema, together. So, to consolidate these values into one total. Can anyone help? SQL I have so far is below:

```
select /*+parallel*/ 'DB1' link,
s.owner,
s.segment_name,
'T' AS FLAG,
sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024 AS SUM_BYTES
from DBA_SEGMENTS@DB1 s
where s.owner = (select distinct productionschema from tables_list_tbl)
and s.segment_name in (select table_name
from tables_list_tbl) and
s.segment_type LIKE '%TABLE%'
group by s.owner, s.segment_name
union all
select 'DB1' link, i.table_owner AS OWNER,
i.table_name AS SEGMENT_NAME,
'I' AS FLAG,
sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024 AS SUM_BYTES
from DBA_SEGMENTS@DB1 s,
DBA_INDEXES@DB1 i
where i.table_owner  = (select distinct productionschema from tables_list_tbl) and
i.table_name in (select table_name
from tables_list_tbl) and
i.owner = s.owner and
i.index_name = s.segment_name and
s.segment_type like '%INDEX%'
group by i.table_owner, i.table_name
union all
select 'DB1' link, l.owner,
l.table_name AS SEGMENT_NAME,
'L' AS FLAG,
sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024 AS SUM_BYTES
from DBA_SEGMENTS@DB1 s,
ALL_LOBS@DB1 l
where l.owner = (select distinct productionschema from tables_list_tbl) and
l.table_name in (select table_name
from tables_list_tbl) and
l.owner = s.owner and
l.segment_name = s.segment_name
group by l.owner, l.table_name
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Anything that gets me LINK, OWNER, SEGMENT_NAME, SUM_BYTES with SUM_BYTES being one total, instead of listed on the basis of each segment type as it is now. I would like the value a total of all three in one numeric value.

Comment: sum() over partition will do it for you

Comment: sum()... sorry that makes no sense to me... I have no partition entry in the code